# Daylight Savings Time wrongly identified by Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, timezone, dst

I'm having an issue with timezones, DST and Node.js. It doesn't identify correctly DST effects. My OS is Windows 8.1 and have the timezone value and DST well set. I tried these two methods:

**1) Node's Date Object**

I typed the following code in Node Prompt and received the answer in italic:

```
new Date()
```

*Tue Sep 09 2014 18:42:36 GMT-0200 (Horário brasileiro de verão(Brazilian Daylight Savings Time))*

However, the brazilian DST starts just in Oct 19th, we are not in DST right now. Therefore, the hour is shifted 1 hour from now.

**2) node-time**

I got node-time package from npm, to be able to change Timezone. In the code:

```
time = require('time');
dateFormat = require('dateformat');

now = time.Date();
console.log(dateFormat(now.setTimezone('America/Sao_Paulo').getTime(), "yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:ss Z"))
```

and as a result, I got

*2014-09-09 18:42:36 GMT-0200*

Brazilian normal timezone is GMT-0300. Hour is also 1 hour shifted.

**Am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The node-time package [does not work on Windows](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-time/issues/13).  I couldn't even get it installed, so I'm not sure how you did.  You should uninstall it.

If you need support for non-local time zones in Node (or in the browser), I recommend [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) with the [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) plugin.

Running `new Date()` on Windows with the time zone set for Brazil, I get the correct output.

[image: Time Zone Settings]

[image: tzutil output]

[image: node output]

The only thing that would explain your results is if the time zone registry settings were modified - but then you'd also see the wrong time in your system clock on your taskbar.  So I'm sorry, but I cannot reproduce that part of it.

Comment: Hi Matt! Thanks a lot. In fact, the timezone had no effect in the node-time package (although it was successfully installed). The error I was getting is due to a TZ env variable I had set and forgot to remove. It was enough in Node to install [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) and now it's working perfectly.