# Node JS current DST rules for Chile

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, utc, dst

According to specifications, Node JS (ES5) should use current dts rules when working with Date objects. Current means "for now", not for a particular date. That's not perfect, but enough for me at this moment.

Currently that rules are wrong (due to law changes in Chile).

Simple probe:

```
console.log(new Date()) 
Mon Apr 08 2019 12:48:08 GMT-0300 (Chile Summer Time) {}
```

shows "(Chile Summer Time)" at the end of the default toString for a date. Actually we are not in Summer Time (it ended two days ago) and current offset should be -4 and not -3.

I tried upgrading Node to lates stable release and didn't work. I Don't want to change a lot of code (in production) to use moment.js or equivalent.

Is there any way to update DST rules in an existing Node JS installation?

Thanks in advance

-- Edit --

TZ environment variable is empty.

Tested on Mac OSX (Mojave 10.14.4) and Red Hat (4.8.5-36)

moment.js recognizes zone correctly ("America/Santiago" whith moment.tz.guess())

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Daylight Savings Time wrongly identified by Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25753537/daylight-savings-time-wrongly-identified-by-node-js)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The change for Chile you mentioned was part of [IANA TZ data version 2018f](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-October/000051.html), released in October 2018.

Node exposes the tz version via [`process.versions.tz`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_versions).  The current shipping 10.15.3 LTS version returns `2018e`, which explains why you aren't seeing the update.  I assume this will be updated at some future date.

Node gets its IANA data via ICU.  There are instructions for different ways to compile Node's ICU support (`system-icu`, `small-icu`, `full-icu`) documented [here](https://nodejs.org/api/intl.html), which apply if you are building Node yourself from source code. Alas, I cannot find any mechanism for updating Node's ICU data directly, without building Node yourself.

ICU has [documentation](http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone#TOC-Updating-the-Time-Zone-Data) on how to update time zone data without updating all of ICU.   however, I cannot see anywhere that Node is taking advantage of this capability.

Thus, when it comes to updating Node's time zone data - Either it cannot currently be done, or it is poorly documented.  Sorry, I don't have a better answer for you than that.

You did say you were using moment-timezone already, which ships its time zone data independently. If you use only moment functions (rather than the `Date` object), then you should get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks Matt ... great explanation. Unfortunately version 11.13.0 keeps using 2018e.