# Does nodejs or meteor timeshift on summer and winter time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

i couldn't find related posts.
My question is, does nodejs or meteor have time shifting functionality
or do i need to restart the server to have the correct time?

If there is a timeshifting in node or meteor then i would need to test the timeshifting behavior since i use cron like jobs to trigger functionality in my app and it could conflict with a timeshifting behavior.

If there is no timeshifting i would just restart the server on given time to make sure the correct time will be on the server.

In germany timeshifting from summer time to winter time is on the 27.October at 3 o'clock the time will be shifted back to 2 o'clock.

I would be very happy for any related answers.

Comment: How are you calculating date/time within your app?

Comment: Do you mean how i test the time behavior? I use lolex for time traveling. I use moment to get my dates and times.

Comment: Not really, but what are you trying to achieve? As far as I know, Nodejs has no internal built in functionality to shift time to summer or winter. So, maybe if you illustrate your intention behind this question we better help you out.

Comment: Thank you 50% of my question is answered. I have cron like jobs which are triggered on specific times and i wanted to make sure the app behavior does not conflict with timeshifting behavior. The other 50% of my question is does meteor has a timeshifting functionality. If both have not then my question would be is there a way to prevent the restarting of the app which is a convention ? Or is it preferable to just restart the server?

Comment: As far as I know, Meteor also doesn't have a time-shifting functionality just like NodeJS. Now, would you please reword the second question? You say you have cron jobs which are triggered on specific time and basically you're afraid restarting your app would mess up those crons??

Comment: If I understand correctly, as long as the cron package you're using persists its state in the database, you don't have to worry about a thing. Check out [littledata:synced-cron](https://github.com/percolatestudio/meteor-synced-cron)
.

Comment: Example: at 3 o clock there will be something triggered that alters some state. If there would be a time shifting the thing would be triggered 2 times which would be problematic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200954/discussion-between-harry-adel-and-user2502106).

Comment: Sounds like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55577423/node-js-current-dst-rules should give you some understanding of how `Date` works in Nodejs. You may also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989484/eliminating-javascript-daylight-saving-time-gap-a-cross-browser-solution for the specific issue of gap / overlap during DST transition, even though that question is more browser oriented.